# PSelectionEventHandler does not trigger callback

Tags: java, swing, piccolo

I am using Piccolo2D library for drawing nodes on canvas. I've setup PSelectionEventHandler like in Piccolo2D's example at:[SelectionExample.java](http://code.google.com/p/piccolo2d/source/browse/piccolo2d.java/trunk/examples/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/piccolo/examples/SelectionExample.java?r=1021)
and then I set breakpoint in

```
private void nodeSelected(final PNotification n)
{
}   // nodeSelected
```

but when I selected node, callback is not invoked. Why?

***EDIT: (taken from OP's answer)***

Ok, here is the code:

In main JFrame:

```
this.panelMain().panelWorkspace().canvas().addInputEventListener(
this.handlerCanvasSelection());
this.panelMain().panelWorkspace().canvas().getRoot().getDefaultInputManager().
     setKeyboardFocus(this.handlerCanvasSelection());

PNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addListener(this, "nodeSelected",
                PSelectionEventHandler.SELECTION_CHANGED_NOTIFICATION,
                this.handlerCanvasSelection());

private void nodeSelected(final PNotification n)
{
}   // nodeSelected
```

Comment: You must have a statement in the method on which you can set a breakpoint.

Comment: Yes, i know that, I had System.print.out("Node selected") inside it, it was typo mistake ...

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your use of `addInputEventListener`.

Comment: Ok, here is the code: In main JFrame: this.panelMain().panelWorkspace().canvas().addInputEventListener(this.handlerCanvasSelection()); this.panelMain().panelWorkspace().canvas().getRoot().getDefaultInputManager().setKeyboardFocus(this.handlerCanvasSelection()); PNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addListener(this, "nodeSelected", PSelectionEventHandler.SELECTION_CHANGED_NOTIFICATION, this.handlerCanvasSelection()); private void nodeSelected(final PNotification n) { } // nodeSelected Is here that I make mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `nodeSelected()` method that is registered as a callback is declared `private`. The implementation of `PNotificationCenter.addListener()` uses reflection to lookup and register the callback method. It actually uses `Class.getMethod()` which returns only public methods. So if the method is not found (for whatever reason) the listener is not registered.

Consider this simple example that demonstrates `SELECTION_CHANGED_NOTIFICATION` notifications:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.*;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.nodes.*;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolox.event.*;

public class TestSelectHandle {

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestSelectHandle");
        PCanvas canvas = new PCanvas() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(100, 200);
            }
        };

        final JTextArea output = new JTextArea(5, 20);

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                canvas, output);
        frame.add(splitPane);

        final PNode blueRect = PPath.createRectangle(50, 50, 50, 50);
        blueRect.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.getLayer().addChild(blueRect);

        final PNode redRect = PPath.createRectangle(110, 110, 50, 50);
        redRect.setPaint(Color.RED);
        canvas.getLayer().addChild(redRect);

        canvas.removeInputEventListener(canvas.getPanEventHandler());
        canvas.removeInputEventListener(canvas.getZoomEventHandler());

        PSelectionEventHandler selectionHandler = new PSelectionEventHandler(
                canvas.getLayer(), canvas.getLayer());
        canvas.addInputEventListener(selectionHandler);
        canvas.getRoot().getDefaultInputManager()
                .setKeyboardFocus(selectionHandler);

        PNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addListener(
                new NodeSelectionListener(output), "selectionChanged",
                PSelectionEventHandler.SELECTION_CHANGED_NOTIFICATION,
                selectionHandler);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class NodeSelectionListener {
        private JTextArea output;

        public NodeSelectionListener(JTextArea output) {
            this.output = output;
        }

        public void selectionChanged(final PNotification notfication) {
            output.append("selection changed\n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```